# Reqular expression for underscore C#

Tags: c#, regex

I need a Reqular expression to identify string in following format in my C# code. The string will always start with "REG" and contain 3 underscores with 2 words and one number between the underscores. See below example:

```
Example: "REG_SOFTWARE_SECURITY_1234"
```

I used below REGEX expression suggested by your forums:

```
"\b[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\b"
```

But it passes the incorrect inputs also like:

```
REG_1234
```

So, it should only pass input in format - "REG_SOFTWARE_SECURITY_1234"  Any suggestions?

Comment: There's nothing special about underscore. Why didn't it work?

Comment: what you get, and what expected output?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how to [ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will increase the chances of getting proper response.

A better way to phrase this question would be ... How your data looks like .... what your expression is fetching and what is the expected result.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava modified my question with sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backslashes in your search string are not being interpreted as you expect. The C# string `"\b[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\b"` starts and ends with a "backspace" 0x0008 character.

To match the example string you need to use either `"\\b[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\b"` or `@"\b[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\b"` as the regular expression.

If the task is to match a string with two words and one number separated by three underscores then the following should work:

@"\b[a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+_[0-9]+\b"

Comment: Thanks. But this expression passes incorrect inputs also like "REG_1234". It should only pass input strings which start with "REG" and contain 3 underscores ,  with 2 words and one number between the underscores, like "REG_SOFTWARE_SECURITY_1234"

Comment: @user5593927 Now you have changed the question. Please give several examples of what you want to match and several more with what you do not want to match.

Comment: thanks again. Yes, I had modified my question, sorry to mention. Your latest expression also works but not for comma. So my input strings will only contain 3 words and one number separated by three underscores. No other character should pass the Regex. E.g. below input has a comma and should fail - "REQ_WRN_ELD_018, REQ_WRN_ELD_020"
I changed your Regex and added check for comma @"\b[^,]+[a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+_[0-9]+\b" but still it is passing the commas. So what is wrong here ?

Comment: @user5593927 Your string `REQ_WRN_ELD_018, REQ_WRN_ELD_020` matches twice. My answer uses `\b` because you used them in the original question. If you want to match against the whole string then change the expression to start with `^` and end with `$`, instead of the `\b`'s.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see issue with your regex. You might be using it incorrectly in c#.

Try this

```
var str="ALPHABET_ ALPHABET _ ALPHABET _99";
var res = Regex.Matches(str,@"\b[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\b");

foreach (Match match in res)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

[**Fiddle Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/w7j9rI)

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean a letter by `ALPHABET` ?

then you could try `\w+_ \w+ _ \w+ _\d+`, if you intended whitespaces, and you are searching for words, not just letters.

If you want to find a pattern like `Letter Underscore Blank` etc. , try  `\w_ \w _ \w _\d`.